# If en Jframe Netbeans

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo una duda yo he ejecutado este programa en la que en netbeans hace una sentencia de que si dinero es menor a total salga `cantidad no suficiente` y, si la vuelve a digitar, y esta vez sí es suficiente, entonces saldrá la factura.

Yo sé cómo ejecutarlo por java, pero no sée cómo este mismo procedimiento se haría en un `JFrame` con ventanas.

Por ejemplo, si dijito un precio en un `TextField`, este vendría siendo dinero como esta planteado en el if, y total vendría siendo otro `TextField` con otra cantidad.

```
if (dinero< total){
            System.out.println("el dinero es INSUFICIENTE.");
            System.out.println("\n si desea cambiar la cantidad de dinero digite CORREGIR, sino no lo desea digite CANCELAR");
            respuesta= leer.next();
             if(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("corregir")){
                 option= true;
             }else{
                 if(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("cancelar")){
                     System.out.println("pedido cancelado.");
                     option=false;
                 }else{
                 System.out.println("el pedido fue cancelado.");
                 }
             }
        }
        }while(money<total && option!= false);

//--devuelta--//
        double devuelta; 

        if (money>= total){
            devuelta= total-money;
            System.out.println("Restaurante el Mirador:");
            System.out.println("FACTURA:");
```

Comment: Para empezar compartiste un código parcial que contiene partes de un bucle `do` sin las variables que usas. No es visible de donde viene `dinero` y/o `money`. Quizas sería bueno de tomar un paso para atras, compartir el artefacto completo que tienes (todo el código del archivo que trabajas actualmente) para que se puede ver donde empiezas a perderte. Si quieres, te puedes unir al [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) para que puedes recibir mejor orientación. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tienes tu jtextfield donde se ingresara el monto y el boton para confirmar**

```
private javax.swing.JButton btnConfirmar;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtDinero;
```

para utilizar los eventos al dar click al boton tu Jframe debe implementar la interfaz ActionListener asi

```
public class Vista extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener
```

entonces tienes que sobreescribir el metodo actionPerformed asi

```
 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    double total = 2000;
    double monto = Double.parseDouble(txtDinero.getText());
    if (monto < total) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MONTO INSUFICIENTE");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MONTO SUFICIENTE GENERANDO FACTURA");
    }
}
```

en tu metodo constructor agregas un actionListener a tu boton asi

```
public Vista() {
    initComponents();
    btnConfirmar.addActionListener(this);

}
```

ojala te sirva como guia

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que te entendí es que no tienes problemas con tu código sino que quieres pasarlo a una interfaz gráfica no? si ese es el caso y ya sabes los básico de como funciona la interfaz te sugiero lo siguiente:

Haz tu interfaz, coloca los jTextFileds que necesites y de ahi en tu código trae los datos que le mete el usuario con un `jTextfield.getText()` es decir, en lugar de escanear lo cambias por el método que te puse. Luego crea un boton y le das dobleclick para ir a su apartado dentro del código, ya estando ahí agregas tu método, el código que pusiste en este post (obviamente completo y con las modificaciones que te dije) y a tu método tambien le agregas `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "tu mensaje");` y esto lo pones en los apartados de los `if`. 
Ya para lo demás ve viendo como quieres que funcione tu interfaz y le vas modificando cosas, suerte.